# How to pass class name to selector?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a button in my table, I want to remove a complete row on button click.?
please dont try to modify the logic i used.

Currently when the button is clicked I get its `id` and based on that `id` i need to delete an element(complete row) from the DOM having same class name.

JavaScript

```
$(".removeAKA").click(function () {
    // alert($(this).val());
    var id = this.id;
    alert(id);
    $("." + id).remove();
});
```

​HTML

```
<tr class="aka 1" id="sdf">
  <td>AKA 1</td>
  <td><input class="text-box single-line" id="aka_1_" name="aka[1]" type="text" value="2" /></td>
  <td><input type="button" class="removeAKA" id="aka 1" value="Delete" /></td>
</tr>​
```

[Here is my code in a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EFmRM/4/)

Comment: You need to learn how to format your questions correctly .... what a mess !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hiya **demo** if you want to keep the spaces: http://jsfiddle.net/59RA2/9/ **OR**  http://jsfiddle.net/59RA2/31/ **OR** http://jsfiddle.net/59RA2/32/

Hope this helps.

I have replaced spaces to `.` because spaces is not recognized when Jquery tries interpreting your code.

**or**

You can also use `$(this).closest('tr').remove();` to remove the row.

**or**
You can use  `$("table ."+id).remove();`

Further:

[jQuery: selector (classname with space)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988483/jquery-selector-question-classname-with-space)

[jQuery remove table row with non-standard id characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382832/jquery-remove-table-row)

**Quote**

> Class names can't have spaces in them. What you have there is two
>   classes:
>
> This div has two classes: panel and
>   current. That's easily selected:
>
> $("div.panel.current")... That means select all divs that have class
>   panel and class current.

**Code**

just replace spaces with . and it will work if you want to else you can have no spaces in-between.

Have a good one, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Class names and IDs can't have spaces in them. Remove the spaces, format your HTML properly, and it will work.

Your example: http://jsfiddle.net/EFmRM/7/

Isolated example: http://jsfiddle.net/Pz5pF/

Comment: but i want my id attribute like abc@i .because i am assigning id to multiple buttons inside for loop

Comment: Can you elaborate on the issue/provide more code? As I mentioned, class names *cannot* have spaces in them. A space in the class attribute acts as a separator.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(".removeAKA").click(function () { 
   $(this).remove();
});
```

//id should not contain spaces

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(this).parent().remove();
```

Comment: `$(this).parents('tr').eq(0).remove();` just to be sure :p

Comment: `$(this).parents('tr:eq(0)').remove();`

Answer (score 0):

remove space in the id and classname. This is not a proper naming convention. Use 'aka1' or 'aka_1' instead of 'aka 1' .Then your code will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one...

```
$(this).parent().remove();
```

I have tested this one in jsfiddle.